# Reassigning a generic Java variable

Tags: java, generics

I'm slightly confused why the following does not compile:

```
public <E extends Object> E doSomething() {
    return new Object();
}
```

I've researched the problem a little and found various fixes like casting to an (E) or using Class Literals but I'm still unsure what is actually wrong with the above.

Comment: and i am confused what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Consider: ``E`` might be ``String``: ``String s = doSomething();`` (see Type Inference).

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because, while `E` will always be an instance of type `Object`, `Object` will never be an instance of type `E`, except for the following case:

```
Object o = doSomething();  //If your code compiled, this call would work
```

In all other cases, you would have a problem. Consider this call in the context of the code you have posted.

```
String s = doSomething();
```

This wouldn't work because your code would always try to return an `Object`, even though you really wanted a `String`.  The compiler is saving you from running into this situation at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return an `Object` in a method whose signature says that it returns an `E`, and which claims that `E` can be any subclass of `Object`.  If `E` is any subclass at all, then an `Object` just isn't good enough to claim to be an `E`.